# Getting text between partial limiters/phrases

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, split

Trying to figure out a way to get the text(inclusive) between two predictable elements in a string.

**Example:**

Full String = `[http:Something] One Two Three [http:AnotherOne] Four [http:BlahBlah] sdksaod,cne 9ofew {}@:P{`

**Ideal result:**

String1 =  `[http:Something] One Two Three`

String2 = `[http:AnotherOne] Four`

String3 = `[http:BlahBlah] sdksaod,cne 9ofew {}@:P{`

Currently I can get the result out, but it's pretty messy and may be harder to update later. Any better ways to do this?

**Current code example:**

```
String par = "[http//blah.com] One Two Three [http://wow.com] Four Five 
[http://another.com] Six";

String[] paramUrls = par.Split(' ');
List<String> paramPerURL = new List<String>();

String temp = "";
Boolean found = false;
for(int z = 0; z < paramUrls.Length; z++){
    if(paramUrls[z].Contains("[http")){                    
        if(found){
            paramPerURL.Add(temp);
        }
        found = true;
        temp = paramUrls[z] + " ";
    } else{
        temp += paramUrls[z] + " ";
    } 
    if(z == paramUrls.Length -1){
        paramPerURL.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative no-regex method using [string.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split).

```
string pattern = "[http";

string[] output = input.Split(new[] { pattern }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(res => pattern + res).ToArray();
```

Since `Split()` removes the delimiter(s) from the string elements it produces, we recombine these results adding back the delimiter using Linq [Enumerable.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) method to generate a new value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your string is composed of parts that start with a `[text]` sequence. If that's the case, and you are sure that the `[` character will never appear as part of the data, you can do something like this:

```
stringParts = Regex.Split(par, @"(?=\[)").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```

Or you could use just `par.Split('[')`, but in that case the initial `[` will be removed from the resulting string parts.

Comment: Sadly can't guarantee the content won't contain "["

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with regular expressions:

```
string str = "[http:Something] One Two Three [http:AnotherOne] Four [http:BlahBlah] sdksaod,cne 9ofew {}@:P{";
string pattern = @"(\[http:Something\].*)(\[http:AnotherOne\].*)(\[http:BlahBlah\].*)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
var match = regex.Match(str);
Console.WriteLine("String 1 : " + match.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine("String 2 : " + match.Groups[2]);
Console.WriteLine("String 3 : " + match.Groups[3]);
```

Comment: Don't always know the exact URL being processed in the [] which would make this solution difficult